# Group of people talk exactly the same simultaneously and it's not always a singing, what is it called?

Tags: word-request

Someone (**S**) gives their speech, then after some time somebody (one or more of them, from **S**'s audience or they can't even hear and see **S**) starts talking and their speech is exactly the same (words, speed) as of **S**. It is used to show connectivity between people (like "great minds speak alike"); the best synonym for this word I can think of is "hivemind speech"

As an example, Dr. Stone, s1ep17 (T+55 seconds from the beginning)

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: Is this the video you're asking about?  https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/dr-stone/videos/235276  If it is, I'm confused by the question, because firstly, there is nothing like that happening at 0:55, although there *is* something like that at about 0:40.  But the people then are not saying exactly the same words at the same speed.  Maybe I am not understanding it well because the original is in Japanese, but to me it just sounds like multiple people reacting to the same event.

Comment: Yes, this video I mean, timecode is still T+55
Senku says "tatoeba" (subt: "for example"), then he and Byakuya starts talking synchronously with the same words (subt: "there should be a delay between average times...") 
At 0:40 they are just talking over each other, words are different, and ofc it's not an example of what I mean

Comment: Thank you, now I understand better what you mean.  It's almost hard to hear it as two different voices speaking in unison if you don't already know that's what's happening!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to give the link, and the link suggested by @stangdon is a science fiction story, and in any case I don't see anything like what you're describing at t+0:55.

It sounds like you're talking about some science fiction or fantasy scenario where people become mindless drones of a leader and repeat his words like automatons. If so, I don't know of any word for that in English because it's not real and it's not a routine fantasy. You would have to describe it for your audience. You might include words like "hivemind", but of itself that would not convey the idea.

There is a common practice of a group of people reciting some prepared words together, like people reciting a pledge to their nation or flag, or new members of an organization reciting an oath, people at a religious service reciting words from their scripture, etc. This is called "unison", as in "speaking in unison" or "reciting in unison". In such cases the text to be recited must be known in advance and either memorized or displayed some way for the speakers to see it. Or how would they know what to say? Not the same as having their minds controlled by someone, where presumably they know what to say because the words are being fed to their brains. But if you wanted to express this idea, you could say, "Under the control of Dr S, the crowd all spoke in unison ..."

I wouldn't expect there to be widely used and recognized English words for every weird science fiction scenario anyone could think of. Yes, some such ideas are so well known that we have words for them, like "stargate" or "cyborg". But not many.

Answer (score 0):

This obviously isn't "real", and there is not particular term for this in common English.  There may be a technical term in filmmaking or theatre.  However, you can borrow a term from singing: These people are speaking **in unison**.